# AvalonDoc 2 Vertical and Horizontal orientation

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I would like to know how I can implement this design. I can't realize this element.

```
<xcad:LayoutRoot>
            <xcad:LayoutPanel>
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                  DockHeight="*">
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="150"
                                                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tool 1">
                                <TextBox />
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Doc1">
                                <TextBox />
                            </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="150"
                                                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tool 1">
                                <TextBox />
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
```

In this picture I drew an element down

http://gyazo.com/f89ea3cc4ec8827173726be9c4c186a7

Answer (score 4):

You should in main `LayoutPanel` set orientation to `Vertical` and add new `LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup`.

Try this:

```
<xcad:DockingManager>
    <xcad:LayoutRoot>
        <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                          DockHeight="*">
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="150"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tool 1">
                            <TextBox />
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                        <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Doc1">
                            <TextBox />
                        </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="150"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tool 1">
                            <TextBox />
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockHeight="150">
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tool 1">
                        <TextBox />
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
        </xcad:LayoutPanel>
    </xcad:LayoutRoot>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```